# Elias M. Stein Real analysis Chapter 1 exercise 5 (b)

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

**My question is :
A complement of the cantor-like sets intersect with $(0,1)$ could be the answer of 5-(b)?**

> Elias M. Stein, *Real Analysis*, Chapter 1 exercise 5 (b)
>
> Suppose $E$ is a given set, and $O_n$ is the open set
> $O_n=\{x : d(x,E)<1/n\}$. Show:
>
> 1. If $E$ is compact, then $m(E)=\lim_{n \to \infty}m(O_n)$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.
> 2. However, the conclusion in (a) may be false for $E$ open and bounded.

Some people answered as you should change some of the cantor-like sets.
However, in my opinion, the cantor-like sets are enough if we assume
$k^{th}$ stage of the construction of the cantor-like sets, removing open intervals each of length is strictly bigger than $0$. for each $k$

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{q_k\}$ be an enumeration of the rationals in $(0,1)$, and let $0 < \epsilon < 1$. Then the set $$E = \bigcup_{k} \,\,(q_k - \epsilon/2^{k+1}, q_k + \epsilon/2^{k+1})$$ is bounded, open and $$m(E) \le \sum_k \frac{\epsilon}{2^{k}} = \epsilon.$$ However, for any fixed $n$, the set $O_n = \{x \, : \, d(x,E) < \frac 1 n\}$ covers $(0,1)$ since any member of $(0,1)$ is within $1/n$ of some rational number in $(0,1)$. Thus $m(O_n) \ge 1$, and the limit cannot hold.

Comment: Thanks for your specific example. It gives me a more detailed view of the situation.

Comment: @2line I see I didn’t read the question closely enough. To answer your question: yes, you could take the complement of a fat Cantor set. The complement is dense, open and has measure less than 1, which is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. It was what I want thanks!!